# Why did the office of Nasi cease to exist?

Tags: history, nasi

In the work *From the Maccabees to the Mishnah (Shaye J. D. Cohen, 2014)* he states that the office of the Nasi ceased to exist around the year 425 CE (p.220), but does not explain why this is so. I would like to know the reason that the office of the Nasi ceased.

Answer (score 7):

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raban_Gamaliel_VI) on Wikipedia:

> Gamaliel probably died in 425, as the [Codex Theodosianus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Theodosianus) mentions an edict from the year 426, which transformed the patriarch's tax into an imperial tax after the death of the patriarch. [Theodosius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodosius_II) did not allow the appointment of a successor and in 429 terminated the Jewish patriarchate.